# three.js MeshBasicMaterial Why is this color different，just look at the picture

Tags: three.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIPe2.png)

Why is this color different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is a bug in the material browser. The color from the color picker is in sRGB color space. If the color value is used as a diffuse color, it has to be convert to linear before rendering when a sRGB workflow is in place (which is true for the material browser).

Let me file a PR to fix this issue.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/23948

Comment: I need to sync colors between dom and three js and found that I got pretty close with applying `filter:rightness(2)` to the dom elements